# SVG package runs Inkscape with invalid command line args

Tags: svg, inkscape

There are many questions on `\includesvg` already, so

- yes, I have added `--shell-escape` to `latexmk`, `lualatexmk` and `pdflatex` in `.vscode\settings.json`.

  Alternatively I have also put `set_tex_cmds( '--shell-escape %O %S' );` in my `.latexmkrc` file.
- yes, I have Inkscape in my `%PATH%` and I have restarted VS Code. In the VS Code terminal I get

  ```
   > inkscape --version
   Inkscape 1.0.2-2 (e86c870879, 2021-01-15)
   Pango version: 1.48.2
  ```
- yes, I am not using an extension in `\includesvg{xxx}`.

Still, my `\includesvg` fails. The LaTeX compiler output says

> Warning: Option --without-gui= is deprecated
>
> Warning: Option --file= is deprecated
>
> Warning: Option --export-pdf= is deprecated
>
> Unknown Option -z

And somewhere in the log file I find similar stuff:

> ```
> runsystem(inkscape -z -D --export-latex  --file="img/xxx.svg" --export-pdf="xxx_svg-tex.pdf" )...executed.
> ```

It seems to me as if I should change how `runcommand()` calls Inkscape. Where would I do that?

Comment: As always on the site please provide a full but minimal example that others can test. It would also be usefull to know which latex installation  you're using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to ugrade from TexLive 2020 to TexLive 2021. It comes with a newer version of the `svg` package which calls Inkscape correctly and fixes [bug 25](https://github.com/mrpiggi/svg/issues/25).

Comment: Well, actually `svg 2020/11/26 v2.02k` is available with Tex Live 2020. You only would have to update via `tlmgr update`

Comment: @mrpiggi I tried, but it said that cross version updates are not allowed. Maybe I did something wrong.